# Exporting a function pointer from dll

Tags: c, windows, dll, function-pointers

I have a function pointer in a dll file (in implementation, not header). How can I call the function pointed to by this pointer in the exe source code?

Comment: If it is declared with global scope then you can just export the variable directly. That's pretty open to abuse though.

Comment: how to abuse it, in what way?

Comment: It's just not very well encapsulated. But it is perfectly normal and common to export variables from DLLs. And a function pointer is just a variable.

Answer (score 2):

you can export a function returning the pointer.
Header:

```
typedef void ( *MyPtr ) ();

__declspec( dllexport ) MyPtr GetMyPtr();
```

Source:

```
MyPtr GetMyPtr()
{
  //retunr the function pointer here
}
```

Comment: Or better and more flexible, fill in a struct of function pointers passed by pointer.