# Exporting a function, cast into a pointer through a DLL

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers, dllexport

This is an elaboration to an earlier question: [How to reset state machines when unit testing C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519285/how-to-reset-state-machines-when-unit-testing-c)
There is also a similar question but i don't the answer match my problem and i have some examples i wish to present: [Exporting a function pointer from dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764074/exporting-a-function-pointer-from-dll)

I have two sets of code that i expect should do the same but the latter crashes.
Using mingw32 and Win7.

The function to be exported. This is to be considered legacy and unmutable.
addxy.c

```
    int addXY(int x, int y)
    {
      return x + y;
    }
```

addxy.h

```
    int addXY(int x, int y);
```

### The working example

main.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "addxy.h"

    typedef int (__cdecl *addXYWrap_t)(int a, int b);

    addXYWrap_t addXYWrap = (addXYWrap_t)addXY;

    void main()
    {
      printf("result: %d", addXYWrap(3, 4));
    }
```

Yielding

```
result: 7
```

### The crashing example

addxydll.c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "addxy.h"

    typedef int (__cdecl *addXYWrap_t)(int a, int b);

    __declspec(dllexport) addXYWrap_t addXYWrap = (addXYWrap_t)addXY;
```

main.c

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef int (__cdecl *func)(int a, int b);

    void main()
    {
      HINSTANCE loadedDLL = LoadLibrary("addxy.dll");

      if(!loadedDLL) {
        printf("DLL not loaded");
        return;
      } else {
        printf("DLL loaded\n");
      }

      func addition = (func)GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, "addXYWrap");

      if(!addition) {
        printf("Func not loaded");
        return;
      } else {
        printf("Func loaded\n");
      }

      printf("result: %d", addition(3, 4));
    }
```

Yielding

```
DLL loaded
Func loaded
```

before it chrashes.

The crash gives no information as to why or what.
Is it a syntactical error or conceptional one?

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` is to specify that you're exporting the function. In this case you're neither importing or exporting since you're doing a runtime lookup so remove the specifier.

Comment: `GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, "addXYWrap");` <- this gives you the *address of* addXYWrap - it returns a `func*`, not a `func`!

Comment: @immibis func is already a function pointer type.

Comment: @Olipro Yeah, and in this case GetProcAddress returns a pointer to a function pointer.

Comment: @immibis Ah yes, correct. He should be exporting the function itself rather than the function pointer. Or alternatively he can dereference the `GetProcAddress()` result of course.

Comment: @Olipro my reason for not exporting the function itself is that i have no control over `addxy.c`and `addxy.h` which makes it difficult to change the declaration of `addXY(int x, int y)`. Another reason that i did not mention is that from time to time i might need to export a function that is not in the legacy code header, only in the source. It's for testing purposes.

Comment: @Enok82 So what? Then just create a wrapper function around it, not a function pointer. `__declspec(dllexport) int myAddXY(int x, int y) { return addXY(x, y); }`

Comment: @Olipro i did that in my previous solution to my question mentioned in the beginning. I did however want to try this version as well since i feel it gives a cleaner look if there are more than only one function to be exported. Also, since it's apparently not wrong to do it like this, just for kicks! ;)

Comment: @Enok82 well, it works. I would argue it's "wrong" on the basis of it being unnecessary and will result in an unecessary extra CPU instruction in order to make the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> func addition = (func)GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, "addXYWrap");
> ```

This call to `GetProcAddress` returns the *address of `addXYWrap`*, not its value. Since `addXYWrap` is a function pointer (of the same type as `func`), that means it returns a pointer to a function pointer, or a `func*`.

Try changing that line to this:

```
func addition = *(func*)GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, "addXYWrap");
```

Or, alternatively:

```
func* addition = (func*)GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, "addXYWrap");
```

and then `(*addition)(3, 4)`

Comment: Damn right you are sire! I went with the first variant, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So, based on comments above, you appear to be overthinking it. If you did *need* a function pointer, then to correctly call it, you must first dereference `GetProcAddress` like so:

```
func addition = *(func*)GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, "addXYWrap");
```

However, a much more convenient solution is to just wrap the function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int myAddXY(int x, int y)
{
    return addXY(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int addXY(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}
__declspec(dllexport) addXYWrap_t addXYWrap = (addXYWrap_t)addXY;
```

This is an error. You have to export function, not a global pointer. That is,

```
/* addxy.c */
__declspec(dllexport) int addXY(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}
....
/* main.c */
func addition = (func)GetProcAddress(loadedDLL, "_addXY");
```

Comment: The question is asking how to export a function pointer from a DLL, not a function.